# Can bash autocomplete be used with the builtin "source" command?

Tags: bash

I have a project where I'm regularly switching out different versions of a library. I have a script `set_lib` that takes the library version as input and then sets the relevant environment variables. Sometimes I want to source this script and build/run things manually. I know how to configure autocomplete for functions/scripts, but what about for sourcing scripts? That is

```sh
>source set_lib v<tab><tab>
ver1 ver2 ver3
```

Also, I would like to keep autocomplete working as normal with `source` when not in conjunction with `set_lib`.

EDIT: As suggested I tried the following

```
_comp_set_lib() {
    if [ ${COMP_WORDS[1]} == 'set_lib' ]; then
        COMPREPLY=( "set_lib ver1" "set_lib ver2" )
    fi
}
complete -o bashdefault -F _comp_set_lib source
```

`$COMP_CWORD` being the second position is giving me problems. The above doesn't work as expected and gives me

```
>source set_lib <tab>
source set_lib ver
```

Comment: What problems is COMP_CWORD being 2 giving you? What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 4):

I think the most convenient approach is to define a function that wraps `source set_lib ...`:

```
function set_lib() {
  source set_lib "$@"
}
```

and then set up autocompletes for that function.

But if you prefer to have to type `source set_lib` and not just `set_lib`, then you can attach an autocompletion function to the `source` builtin, and have it check whether `"${COMP_WORDS[1]}"` (meaning the first argument to `source`) equals `set_lib` before deciding whether to return any custom matches. (When using the `complete` builtin to set up the autocomplete, use the `-o bashdefault` flag to tell it that if your function doesn't return any matches then you want Bash to fall back to its default logic for suggestions.)

Comment: For the sourcing route, I have trouble with the argument index. I'd like to increment $COMP_CWORD, but I believe it's intended to be read only. Just setting COMPREPLY=( "set_lib ver1" "set_lib ver2" ) did not work as I expected.

Comment: @roro: I'm not totally clear on what you expected, sorry. I would update my answer to give a specific example, but it would basically be what pynexj has posted, so I recommend just trying his/her answer.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you need to invoke `compgen` for custom completion spec. See the following example:

```sh
_comp_set_lib()
{
    local cur=$2
    local versions=(v1 ver2 version3)

    if [[ ${COMP_WORDS[1]} == set_lib ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "${versions[*]}" -- "$cur" ) )
        return
    fi
}
complete -o default -o bashdefault -F _comp_set_lib source
```